# Why opendir() returns directory does not exist on android

Tags: android, c++

I am trying to use `opendir()` function from the `dirent.h` header file on android and everytime I run it, it returns `NULL` with error `ENOENT` meaning directory does not exist.

I am trying to port a C++ game to android and this works fine on Windows.

I've checked the directory and it exists under `assets/pics/Jason`

This is how I call it:

```
DIR *DIRpointer=opendir("pics/Jason");
```

Also tried "`/pics/Jason`"
And "`pics/Jason/`"
And I still got the same error...

I've tried Googling but no solution.

Comment: And you are sure there's a `pics` directory in the programs current working directory? Perhaps the working directory is not what you expect it to be? Have you tried getting and logging the current directory to see what it might be?

Comment: Yes i am sure. I can load an image from the pics directory using IMG_Load("pics/arrow.png")

Comment: Perhaps it's because on POSIX systems (like e.g. Linux, which is used for Android) most filesystems are *case sensitive* while on Windows filesystems generally are not. Is the directory you try to open named `jason` (with lower-case `j`) or `Jason` (with upper-case `J`)?

Comment: Yes I've also checked that. I was paying attention to case sensitivity too

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AAssetManager and AAssetManager_openDir() function if you access the asset directory in android phone

Comment: What is that? Does that involve me writing java code? Or i can use it directly on my C++ source?

Comment: If you put your resource into the assets folder of your app, you can use the jni AAssetManager api to get file directly from C++

Comment: how do i start using AAssetManager api? Do i have to edit SDL_Activity.java? With what? Calling the functions from c++ crashes the app